# Run Length Encoding Python

Tags: python

The question asks: Write a function that takes, as an argument, a list of characters and returns a list reflecting the run-length encoding of that list. The elements in the returned list follow the following pattern: the even indices contain the characters and the odd indices contain the number of times the character is repeated consecutively.

When I type a list into the function, it does not iterate through the whole length of the list. It will work for lists of shorter lengths but not for longer ones.Not sure how to fix it.

```
def runLengthEncoding(myList):
    aList=[]
    count=1
    for i in range(1,len(myList)):
        if myList[i] == myList[i-1]:
            count=count+1
        else:
            aList.append(myList[i-1])
            aList.append(count)
            count=1
            if i == (len(myList)-1):
                aList.append(myList[i])
                aList.append(count)
    return aList
```

Comment: Please show your code (and please don't show a _screenshot of your code_).

Comment: Fixed it @birryree

Comment: What makes you think "it does not iterate through the whole length of the list" for longer lists? Do you have any specific examples of lists it fails on? What specific behavior did you observe that made you think it wasn't iterating through the whole input?

Comment: Now that I'm seeing the code, how does it differ from your previous question and answer? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46555516/run-length-encoding-python - what's not working with your code? Can you show some example input and what happens on it?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is failing when the last item(s) are repeating, or when the length of the list is 1:

```
>>> runLengthEncoding("fooobar")
['f', 1, 'o', 3, 'b', 1, 'a', 1, 'r', 1]
>>> runLengthEncoding("fooobarr")
['f', 1, 'o', 3, 'b', 1, 'a', 1]
>>> runLengthEncoding("a")
[]
```

A fix for your solution would be to remove the three lines starting with `if i == (len(myList)-1):` and replace them with

```
if myList:
    aList.append(myList[-1])
    aList.append(count)
```

Move that block outside the loop.

---

However, the easiest way to implement run-length encoding would probably be with the itertools module:

```
from itertools import chain, groupby

def run_length(iterable):
    return list(chain.from_iterable(
        (val, len([*thing]))
        for val, thing in groupby(iterable)
    ))
```

Comment: Your answer seems overcomplicated. If `myList` is not empty, the `count` will always be valid when the loop terminates. So a simple fix for the original code is to move the last three lines out of the loop, and replace them with `if len(myList) > 0: aList.append(myList[-1]); aList.append(count)`.

Comment: PS: the test `if count > 1` will fail for single terminating characters (e.g. `"a"` or `"abc"`)

Comment: @ekhumoro Not if you keep the original last 3 lines.

Comment: Even with that, it will fail for `"a"`.

Comment: True, because `range(1, 1)` is empty. Will add your proposal to my answer.