# How to count consecutive repetitions in a pandas series

Tags: python, pandas

Consider the following series, `ser`

```
date        id 
2000        NaN
2001        NaN 
2001        1
2002        1
2000        2
2001        2
2002        2
2001        NaN
2010        NaN
2000        1
2001        1
2002        1
2010        NaN
```

How to count the values such that every consecutive number is counted and returned? Thanks.

```
Count
NaN     2 
1       2 
2       3
NaN     2
1       3
NaN     1
```

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27626699/5168011) is what you are looking for?

Comment: @Guy it doesn't seems to work. Maybe becuase of `nan`

Comment: That's basically run length encoding. You'll probably find some implementation when looking for it with your favorite search engine ;)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46572023/run-length-encoding-python check the answers here

Comment: @sophros the tricky part is the NaN which those answers/question doesn't handle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is another approach using `fillna` to handle `NaN` values:

```
s = df.id.fillna('nan')
mask = s.ne(s.shift())

ids = s[mask].to_numpy()
counts = s.groupby(mask.cumsum()).cumcount().add(1).groupby(mask.cumsum()).max().to_numpy()

# Convert 'nan' string back to `NaN`
ids[ids == 'nan'] = np.nan
ser_out = pd.Series(counts, index=ids, name='counts')
```

[out]

```
nan    2
1.0    2
2.0    3
nan    2
1.0    3
nan    1
Name: counts, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Can we replace string `nan` back to double `nan` at the end

Comment: If output is assigned to a new variable `ser_out`, something like `ser_out.index = ser_out.index.where(ser_out.index != 'nan')` maybe..? Or better, `ids[ids == 'nan'] = np.nan` before the `Series` contructor

Answer (score 5):

The cumsum trick is useful here, it's a little tricky with the NaNs though, so I think you need to handle these separately:

```
In [11]: df.id.isnull() & df.id.shift(-1).isnull()
Out[11]:
0      True
1     False
2     False
3     False
4     False
5     False
6     False
7      True
8     False
9     False
10    False
11    False
12     True
Name: id, dtype: bool

In [12]: df.id.eq(df.id.shift(-1))
Out[12]:
0     False
1     False
2      True
3     False
4      True
5      True
6     False
7     False
8     False
9      True
10     True
11    False
12    False
Name: id, dtype: bool

In [13]: (df.id.isnull() & df.id.shift(-1).isnull()) | (df.id.eq(df.id.shift(-1)))
Out[13]:
0      True
1     False
2      True
3     False
4      True
5      True
6     False
7      True
8     False
9      True
10     True
11    False
12     True
Name: id, dtype: bool

In [14]: ((df.id.isnull() & df.id.shift(-1).isnull()) | (df.id.eq(df.id.shift(-1)))).cumsum()
Out[14]:
0     1
1     1
2     2
3     2
4     3
5     4
6     4
7     5
8     5
9     6
10    7
11    7
12    8
Name: id, dtype: int64
```

Now you can use this labeling in your groupby:

```
In [15]: g = df.groupby(((df.id.isnull() & df.id.shift(-1).isnull()) | (df.id.eq(df.id.shift(-1)))).cumsum())

In [16]: pd.DataFrame({"count": g.id.size(), "id": g.id.nth(0)})
Out[16]:
    count   id
id
1       2  NaN
2       2  1.0
3       1  2.0
4       2  2.0
5       2  NaN
6       1  1.0
7       2  1.0
8       1  NaN
```

Comment: output doesn't match the question's output.

Comment: @Oli true, but very close and specifically the OPs output is kinda bad since it has duplicates (and NaN) in the index. With a `reset_index()` it would be the same...

Comment: Agree with Andy here: a unique index has [clear performance benefits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16629125/9209546). Aside, it makes more sense as an "index".