# Count occurrences of char in a single string

Tags: python

```
string = input(" ")
count = string.count()
print(string + str(count))
```

Need to use a for loop to get the output: ll2a1m1a1

Comment: input: llama and then output: ll2a1m1a1

Comment: It's not clear what are you trying to do.

Comment: So you want to count the consecutive occurrences of a character? Also add your comment into the post.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run Length Encoding Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46572023/run-length-encoding-python)

Comment: I need to be able to input any word in the input, not just llama

Answer (score 1):

Use [`groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html) from `itertools`

```py
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> s = 'llama'
>>> [[k, len(list(g))] for k, g in groupby(s)]
[['l', 2], ['a', 1], ['m', 1], ['a', 1]]
```

If you want exactly that output you asked, try the following, and as suggested by @DanielMesejo, use `sum(1 for _ in g)` instead of `len(list(g))`:

```py
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> s = 'llama'
>> groups = [[k, sum(1 for _ in g)] for k, g in groupby(s)]
>>> ''.join(f'{a * b}{b}' for a, b in groups)
'll2a1m1a1'
```

This works for any word you want, let's say the word is 'happen', so

```py
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> s = 'happen'
>> groups = [[k, sum(1 for _ in g)] for k, g in groupby(s)]
>>> ''.join(f'{a * b}{b}' for a, b in groups)
'h1a1pp2e1n1'
```

Comment: I need to be able to use any word, not just llama. And it has to be in a loop to output exactly: if i used the word llama --> ll2a1m1a1

Comment: @DevinMartin, just replace any string you want in `s`, it should work.

Comment: @DanielMesejo, I agree with you. I just updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Look bud, you gotta explain more, this loops through and counts how many times each letter and prints it out.

```
greeting = 'llama'
for i in range(0, len(greeting)):
    #start count at 1 for original instance.
    count = 1
    for k in range(0, len(greeting)):
        # check letters are not the same position letter.
        if not k == i:
            #check if letters match
            if greeting[i] == greeting[k]:
                count += 1
    print(greeting[i] + str(count))
```

Comment: it needs to count the occurrences of each character and print it like this: input --> llama output: ll2a1m1a1 It has to do this with any word you input

Answer (score 0):

a more basic approach:

```
string = 'llama'

def get_count_str(s): 
    previous = s[0]
    for c in s[1:]:
        if c != previous:
            yield f'{previous}{len(previous)}'
            previous = c
        else:
            previous += c


    # yield last
    yield f'{previous}{len(previous)}'

print(*get_count_str(string ), sep='')
```

output:

```
ll2a1m1a1
```