# Extract pattern of string\list to its sequences

Tags: python, algorithm

I need beat up stream of items to its sequences.

For example:

> ```
> aaa bb
> 3a1 2b
>
> ['blah', 'blah', 'yo', 'yo', 'yo']
> 2blah3yo
> ```

There is something bulit-in in python which can help?

This is my naive try:

```
def foo(txt):
  pattern = ""

  start = True
  prev = ''
  counter = 1

  for i in range(len(txt)):
    if i > 0:
      if txt[i] == txt[i-1]:
        counter += 1
      else:
        pattern += str(counter)+txt[i-1]
        counter = 1
    if i == len(txt)-1:
      pattern += str(counter)+txt[i]

  return pattern

print(foo("aaa bb"))
print(foo(["blah", "blah", "yo", "yo", "yo"]))
```

Comment: Why is `aaa` `3a1`? Why not just `3a`?

Comment: 3 "a", 1 space, 2 "b"

Comment: This method is called "run-length encoding". Take a look at the last code snippet from [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46572391/14277568).

Comment: Or try https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding